# How can I scan/fuzz my code for vulnerabilites?

Tags: php, security, testing, fuzzing

I'm looking for an automated way to fuzz my app or scan it for vulnerabilities. Please assume that my hacking knowledge is 0. Also the source is on my localhost so I need a way to fuzz it locally without relying on an internet connection. Can some security experts give me some hints or recommendations? I'm not sure what options are best.

**Edit:**

**Thanks for the effort to answer, but none so far seems to get the point.** I'd like to be more specific (because it helps the question) but without influencing opinions or sounding like I'm advertising a specific product. I'm looking for something like [wapiti](http://wapiti.sourceforge.net/) (sorry to mention names, but had to, because answers so far like learn about sql injections, xss etc. are obviously not real "expert" answers to this question. I already know about these (**seriously, does this question sound like it could asked by someone who doesn't know salt about security?**)

I'm not asking **whether** I should test, I'm asking **how** I should test. I **already decided** to incorporate automation (and there's no turning back in this decision unless someone gives me an expert answer that proves it useless), so please respect my decision that I'd like to automate. I don't want to go through every compiled xss, sql injection, etc. hack list and try it manually myself against my site **(even hackers don't hack that way)**. Super extra points to anyone who gets the question.

**Some people are asking why not just learn.**
Best practices (which I know) are not the same as knowing hacking. Some people want to argue they're a flip-coin, but I definitely don't agree :) hence I need a protection tool by someone with the "hacker mentality". How is that going to hurt, in fact, you should try it too ;) **Expert answers please from those who know.**

Comment: I've been looking for some kind of static code analyzer for years. Mostly, I've been placing my hopes in the new roadsend + LLVM project, its conceivable that it _could_ generate warnings like you want as it compiles.

Comment: "Thanks for the effort to answer, but none so far seems to get the point." - that is because the point cannot be got. Security holes are found by humans using incredible amounts of creativity, effort and trying. If security audits could be replaced by automation, do you think anybody would choose to do them manually?

Comment: @Pekka, You seem to be forgetting the point that such tools already exist. I gave an example of one in my very question, not to mention that hackers every day are probing your sites using variations of them. Ok, enough said :)

Comment: So is your question what are some tools one could use for testing security issues?

Answer (score 7):

There are [services](http://www.mcafee.com/us/enterprise/products/risk_and_compliance/risk_advisor.html) that will do automated scans for vulnerabilities. They will not catch everything, but will help you identify problems. Your best bet is to use one of these services and LEARN SOME SECURITY best practices.

Start learning about [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and [cross site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). these are the biggest and easiest to fix vulnerabilities.

Programming defensively is a skill that IMHO every programmer should learn.

**There is no substitute for understanding these issues on your own.**

Answer (score 3):

To strictly answer your question the way you should test is by using a tool. There are 2 main types of tools you can use, a security scanner which actively probes a running website or a static analysis tool which runs on the source code you use to build your webapp.

The short answer is you want a security scanning tool like wapiti or burp. Tools like these dynamically construct and execute security tests uniquely for your site. You could manually attempt to exploit your own site but that would take lots of time and not provide any value. It would be useless for you to go through a list of known xss or sql injection issues because each issue is unique to the site it applies to. Furthermore these tools can attack your site better then you can giving you a more rigorous security stress test.

There are 2 main tools you can use, static analysis tools and dynamic analysis tools. Static analysis tools read in your source code, figure out the way the data flows through the app and look for security issues. At their root most security issues are allowing a user to control some data that flows into an inappropriate part of an application so even though the app isn't running and you rub up against the halting problem, static analysis method of "guessing" and trying out each code path can yield good results. Static analysis tools are language dependent and most are expensive. Some free ones are fxcop (C#), PMD and findbugs (java), see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis

Dynamic analysis tools (more commonly just called "security scanner") require you setup your webapp so it can run tests against it, this sounds like more what you want. My favorite tool here is burp, some free ones include wapiti which is good as well. These tools will look at how your app handles data, look for inputs and fill them with malicious data in an attempt to trigger vulnerabilities. An example test would be for testing reflected cross-site scripting, the scanner would look at a page and insert javascript into every querystring value, cookie value, form value etc and then render the page to see if the malicious javascript was echod back to the page.

You likely don't need or want a fuzzer. Fuzzing tools mostly help you when there is a lot of parsing code so a fuzzer is not the best fit for a webapp whereas it would be a good fit for a protocol you are making. There is limited fuzzing capabilities in the security scanner tools listed above and you probably don't need more then this. Fuzzers also take time to build. Fuzzers often find more stuff in c/c++ code because there are less libraries built in already doing the right thing, in the webapp case there is less "room for fuzzers to play" so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

Before you go crazy on automation (which will likely yield results you probably won't understand), I'd suggest that you read up of writing secure code instead and learn to identify the things you are doing wrong. Here are some tutorials to get you started:

http://php.net/manual/en/security.php

Failing that, I'd suggest outsourcing your code to a security firm if you can afford it.

Good luck!

Comment: It won't let me post more than one link in the origina, but here are some more: [1] http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/php-security [2] http://phpsec.org/articles/

Comment: Very true, it's like trying to run an automated scan to look for performance problems: you can't automate understanding.

Comment: @Chris: Once you understand the problems related to the positives, they migth be useful, but lack of understanding will result in no return when you get a list of "possible vunerabilities" that mean nothing to the code author. I hope that explians my response a little better.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're assuming I don't understand. I know best-practices, just haven't hacked. But some people want to argue they're the same. I definitely don't agree :) hence I need a protection tool by someone with the "hacker mentality"

Comment: @Chris, I didn't realize at the time you were the question poster. I was answering your comment response as a response to my answer not necessarily directed as a response including your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Provided you know C, You can work with spike, Its always good to do a manual check for overflows in anything that could conceivably be touched by an end-user, The usual %x%x%x tests for format string attacks, and just to be diligent in your static analysis.

PeachFuzz and SPIKE are both well documented.

Failing that, writing your own is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing what fuzzing is and how you may want to approach does not necessarily lead to the skills necessary to thoroughly test and evaluate your software for vulnerabilities and flaws.  You need to use automated testing, but in a tuned manner where you modify the testing that the tool is doing as you find new input paths, interactions, and so on.

Basically, what I'm saying is that you need to know what you are doing if you want this to be a real value add.  You cannot just pick a tool, run it, and expect to get good results.  You need someone who does this type of testing to work either with or for you.  Tools are useful, but can only produce useful results when used by someone skilled in this art.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Paros - http://www.parosproxy.org/ - its free, easy to use and displays both the cause of the error, the possible fix and how to replicate it (usually a link).

It easy to configure and spiders your entire site - it can also spider local installations.

It has a gui as well.

Its old, but its good and easy.

I tried to configure WAPITI but it was simply too hard for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've been researching this topic for many years for my own application and found a fantastic tool recently which was based on PAROS (see my other answer above)

Its ZAP from OWASP and is the ducks nuts.

- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project

One of the best things you can do is integrate ZAP into your project automation / build so whenever you do a build the test runs.

Even better, you can sit it next to your selenium automated tests to 'collect' the pages you test, then......scan the hell out of them!

Its really well documented, but you'll need a fast PC as it runs hundreds of tests per page. If you're doing a whole site it can take some time.

There are some other tools you might want to consider

- http://sqlmap.org/

I found this tool....scarily easy to use and very very comprehensive.

Whenever I got what I thought was a 'false positive' with ZAP, I'd scan the page with SQLmap (you gotta figure out how to use Python - its easy, took a couple of hours) and SQLmap would either verify the false positive or find the vulnerability.